# jQuery returning character at end of 2nd string rather than 1st

Tags: jquery

I currently have code that reads a barcode scanner, puts that string into a textbox which is then passed through to the URL when the text limit of 8 is passed.

The issue is that the final number of the string, is being placed not on the first string for the textbox, but the second string regarding the barcode. (meaning that instead of davie123, we are getting davie12 and davie1233)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

var pageURL = "url"

var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

barcode=barcode+String.fromCharCode(code)
if ($('#scanner').val().length = 8 ){
window.location.href = pageURL + "&param=" + $('#scanner').val() +"&barcode=" + barcode+String.fromCharCode(code);
}


});
```

Comment: Your `if` is invalid , using assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operatror `==` or `===`.

Comment: adding == causes it to require two scans to output parameters to the address bar, it also adds DD to the second string. Any ideas?

Comment: Suggest you do some basic debugging by logging values to console. Where is `barcode` defined? There isn't enough code shown for anyone here to replicate your problem